# Insert table from one database into another database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to copy a table to another database server in SQL developer.
I use this method to solve this problem.

```
INSERT INTO mahdi-jiradb..empier SELECT * FROM tamindb..users;
```

but i get an error:

```
Error starting at line : 8 in command -
INSERT INTO mahdi-jiradb..empier
SELECT * FROM tamindb..users
Error at Command Line : 8 Column : 18
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
00926. 00000 -  "missing VALUES keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What should i do?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @Littlefoot 
Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: That's a **tool**. Database is Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, ...

Comment: @Littlefoot What do you mean?

Comment: You have tagged `SQL Server`. That is `Microsoft SQL Server`. Are you using this ?

Comment: @Squirrel // Oh sorry . No.. Oracle

Comment: I mean exactly what I said, mahdi. A database contains *data* (and procedures, functions, ...). A tool lets you *manipulate* data - insert rows, update values, delete rows, ... create procedures, packages, triggers, ... One of these tools is e.g. Oracle's SQL*Plus (a command-line tool), another is Oracle SQL Developer (GUI tool), etc.

Comment: Also it looks like you meant **schema** rather than **database**. This is one area where Oracle's architecture (or terminology) varies compared to other flavours of RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

As you commented, it looks as if you use Oracle.

In that case, schema name can't contain a "minus" sign (mahdi-jiradb) so that's probably underline (mahdi_jiradb) instead.

```
SQL> create user mahdi-jiradb identified by test;
create user mahdi-jiradb identified by test
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Unless, of course, you enclosed username into double quotes (but now you have to use it always, everywhere):

```
SQL> create user "mahdi-jiradb" identified by test;

User created.
```

Presuming that that's not the case, schema name is *wrong*. Check it.

Also, use one dot to separate schema name from table name.

---

Something like this *might* work:

```
INSERT INTO mahdi_jiradb.empier SELECT * FROM tamindb.users;
```

presuming that both tables share the same description. That's why it is better to explicitly name all columns involved, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mahdi_jiradb.empier (user_id, user_name)
  SELECT uid, uname FROM tamindb.users;
```

Comment: I read your answer four times to understand.
Thanks it was helpful.

Comment: Anything else.
@Littlefoot
I used "underline" and set "double quotes" but for both of them get me an error:
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: Then it is pretty much clear; you don't have access to that table, or it simply doesn't exist. Query ALL_OBJECTS and see whether it is there or not. Do it for both tables involved, in both schemas.

Comment: //How Query ALL_OBJECTS for both tables involved, in both schemas.?

Comment: SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS

Comment: Also note that using double-quotes around object names will get around certain issues, but it will create far more problems.  By default, oracle names are case-INsensitive.  Use of double quotes makes them case-sensitive, which is far less flexible.  Plus, use of double-quotes allows you to use characters (like the minus sign) that you really shouldn't be using in the first place.

Comment: @Littlefoot
I was creating "database Link":
create public database link
  mylink
connect to
  mahdi
identified by
  mahdi
using 'jiradb.ASH';

Comment: @Littlefoot /And use this to copy my table to second database:
SELECT 'insert into'
|| empier_backup
|| 'select * from'
|| users
|| '@mylink'
FROM name;

but get this error:
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: insert into empier select * from tamindb@mylink;
Error report -SQL Error: 12154. 00000 -  "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" *Cause: A connection to a database or other service was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods configured. *Action: - If you are using easy connect naming: - Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the AMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).